# How to extract treatment effect and statistical significance in a Matched pair + diff in diff experiment

Tags: t-test, experiment-design, difference-in-difference

I have a unique experiment setup where for each user i look at the before and after of a metric and also, i have treatment and control group users. So basically my data looks like:

`user   metric_before   metric_after    is_treatment`

Now i could just use diff in diff, but i noticed that in a diff-diff regression, the matched pair concept is ignored and the model is trained as independent rows with no matching of the metric before and after for the same user. Another approach is to take the difference in the metric for each user, do a two sample t-test on the before and after difference between the treatment and control. Which approach is best ?